# Filter by multiple array conditions

Tags: swift

The `filter` method is a really powerful tool for filtering by single or multiple conditions, but is there a way to filter by conditions of arrays?

class `Car` with properties : `model`, `color`, `engineStatus`.

- `cars` is an array with few cars

By one condition would look like:

```
let currModel = `Opel`

let filterdObject = cars.filter { $0.model == currModel }
```

By two or more conditions would look like:

```
let currModel = `Opel`
let currColor = `Green`

let filterdObject = cars.filter { $0.model == currModel || $0.color == currColor }
```

My question is it how could I filter by an array like:

An array has ,e.g., two colors `blue` and `green`. I would like to filter `cars` by these colors. My point is to get a formula for `n-conditions`.

Comment: Something like `cars.filter {arrayOfColors(contains:$0.color)}`?

Comment: @Larme would looks like` cars.filter {arrayOfColors.contains($0.color)}` - new syntax

Comment: I don't use Swift, when I comment on Swift, it's just pointing out what could possibly a way to go, code not assured at all to compile, but understandable. But thanks to correct (in case of someone taking "as such" the indication).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Forget about the filter for a moment. Think how you would check if a car's color is a value in an array.

```
let colors = [ "Green", "Blue" ]
// or let colors: Set = [ "Green", "Blue" ]
if colors.contains(someCar.color) {
}
```

Simple enough. Now use that same simple expression in the filter.

```
let filterdObject = cars.filter { $0.model == currModel || colors.contains($0.color) }
```

Comment: I don't get the downvote either, this is a valid solution... Having said that, a membership test against a `Set` instead of an `Array` could be more suitable here.

Comment: @Alladinian Good suggestion on the use of Set. The OP mentioned having an array.

Answer (score 10):

Treat the filter closures like a value type and store them in an array. Use the inner reduce call to create a single boolean value that is true is all of the conditions are met by the current car. If you need a compound test like color == "blue" or "green" then simply add that to your filter closure conditions array.

```
    struct Car {
      let model: String
      let color: String
    }

    let conditions: [(Car) -> Bool] = [
      {$0.model == "Opel"},
      {$0.color == "Red"},
    ]

    let carLot = [
      Car(model: "Opel", color: "Green"),
      Car(model: "Mustang", color: "Gold"),
      Car(model: "Opel", color: "Red"),
    ]

    let allRedOpels = carLot.filter {
      car in
      conditions.reduce(true) { $0 && $1(car) }
   }
```

Comment: That reduce approach isn't so good because it doesn't perform any short circuiting

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it saved my day and a lot of work!

Answer (score 1):

To piggy-back off [Price Ringo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43348735/8828017) you could use `allSatisfy` instead of `reduce` to get a cleaner read of the code:

```
struct Car {
  let model: String
  let color: String
}

let conditions: [(Car) -> Bool] = [
  {$0.model == "Opel"},
  {$0.color == "Red"},
]

let carLot = [
  Car(model: "Opel", color: "Green"),
  Car(model: "Mustang", color: "Gold"),
  Car(model: "Opel", color: "Red"),
]

let allRedOpels = carLot.filter {
  car in
  conditions.allSatisfy { $0(car) }
}
```