# Filter Array in Swift based on multiple properties

Tags: arrays, swift

```
struct User{
    var firstName:String
    var lastName:String
    var city:String
    var email:String
}

var users = [User]
```

I am trying to filter users as someone is typing in the textfield. Its like Search for the email. It should show all the matching results but shouldn’t duplicate the same user. I am able to filter the array based on one property such as `name` but not sure how to filter the array based on all the properties.

I’ve implemented the UITextField delegate and have this code for filtering.

```
let filteredArray = users.filter({ (user) -> Bool in
    return user.firstName.lowercased().contains(“John”)
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter by multiple array conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348330/filter-by-multiple-array-conditions)

Comment: Let's think about what's the meaning of the `filter()` closure. You iterate the array, the current element is named in your case `user` (that's the param). Then, according to `user` values, you decide to return `true` if you want to keep it, and `false` if you don't. Currently, you return true if the `firstName.lowercased()` contains "John". So check on the other property using an OR between them?

Comment: @Larme I never thought of using OR. You are right. Thanks

Comment: You can use AND also, it really depends on what's the reason to keep the element or not. It can be a "complicated" reason.

Comment: Use **or** (`||`) if you want to increase the number of matches. Use **and** (`&&`) if you only want to match items that meet ALL the criteria.

Comment: Unrelated but `firstName.range(of: "John", options: .caseInsensitive) != nil`  is more efficient than `firstName.lowercased().contains(“John”)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let filteredArray = users.filter({ $0.firstName.lowercased().contains("firstName") || $0.lastName.lowercased().contains("lastName") || ... })
```

Comment: that's a very long line. It's better to split it up.

Answer (score 2):

You can set multiple conditions and combine them together with OR (||) or AND (&&)- its a simple boolean, you can think of it as it was in an if statement-

```
if user.firstName.lowercased().contains("john") || user.lastName.lowerCased().contains("lastname") { return true }
else { return false }
```

so in your code it will be like

```
let filteredArray = users.filter { (user) -> Bool in
return user.firstName.lowercased().contains("john") || user.lastName.lowercased().contains("lastname") }
```

Comment: don't do `if b { return true } else { return false }`. Just do `return b`.

Comment: It doesn't clarify anything. It just adds irrelevant redundancy

Comment: It does because this syntax might be confusing for starting programmers, so I converted it to a simple if statement. A lot of starters have problems understanding that if statement is actually consist from a boolean

Comment: From that perspective (of the absolute beginner), your code is strictly more complex. It requires understanding booleans, if statements and return statements, whereas my suggested code only requires understanding return statements.

Comment: beginners don't consider "user.firstName.lowercased().contains("john") || user.lastName.lowerCased().contains("lastname")" as a single boolean parameter "b"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184283/discussion-between-alexander-and-startingprogrammer).

Answer (score 2):

Since you'll probably need to search multiple things, I would recommend you make a `Searchable` protocol, and make aggregate types searchable by virtue of checking if any of their constituents match.

```
import Foundation

struct User {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let city: String
    let email: String
    let age: Int // an example of a non-String type.
}

protocol Searchable {
    func matches(query: String) -> Bool 
}

extension String: Searchable {
    func matches(query: String) -> Bool {
        // Implement any kind of searching algorithm here. Could be as smart as fuzzy seraching
        // or as basic as this case-insenitive simple substring search
        return self.lowercased().contains(query)
    }
}

extension Int: Searchable {
    func matches(query: String) -> Bool {
        return String(self).matches(query: query)
    }
}


extension User: Searchable {
    func matches(query: String) -> Bool {
        let constituents: [Searchable] = [firstName, lastName, city, email, age]
        return constituents.contains(where: { $0.matches(query: query) })
    }
}
```