# Find objects that include an array that contains all elements of a second array

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to filter a set of objects based on values in one of their elements based on another array.  I've got it working with filter just fine if the search is "OR"  - it returns give me all objects for which at least one of the strings in the search array is found.

But I can't figure out how to make it work as an AND search - returning only the objects that match ALL of the strings in the search array.

Example:

```
struct Schedule {
    let title: String
    let classTypes: [String]
}

let schedule1 = Schedule(title: "One", classTypes: ["math","english","chemistry","drama"])
let schedule2 = Schedule(title: "Two", classTypes: ["pe","math","biology"])
let schedule3 = Schedule(title: "Three", classTypes: ["english","history","math","art"])

let schedules = [schedule1, schedule2, schedule3]

let searchArray = ["math", "english"]

//works for OR - "math" or "english"
var filteredSchedules = schedules.filter { $0.classTypes.contains(where: { searchArray.contains($0) }) }
```

I'd like to find a way for it to use the same search array

> let searchArray = ["math", "english"]

But only return items 1 & 3 - as they both have BOTH math and english in the list.

There are good examples of AND conditions when the AND is across different search criteria: [car type and colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348330/filter-by-multiple-array-conditions/43348446) - but I've been unable to find an example where the criteria are dynamically based on items in an array.  For context, I could have dozens of schedules with 20+ class types.

Comment: So you are trying to find only an exact math. It should return "One" and "Three" but  not "Two" because it has only one item?

Comment: That's correct - it works fine as it is for partial match - but what I can't get is exact.

Comment: Does the order of the elements in your collection matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with a Set, isSubset will return true if the schedules element contains all elements of the searchSet

```
let searchSet = Set(searchArray)
var filteredSchedules = schedules.filter { searchSet.isSubset(of: $0.classTypes) }
```

As suggested by @LeoDabus it might be worth changing the type of `classTypes` to Set instead of arrays (if order doesn't matter) since they seems to be unique and then the filtering can be done in the opposite way without the need to convert `searchArray` each time

```
var filteredSchedules = schedules.filter { $0.classTypes.isSuperset(of: searchArray) }
```

Comment: I was about to suggest that. But I would post `$0.classTypes.isSuperset(of: searchArray)`

Comment: @LeoDabus But them `classTypes` needs to be changed to be a Set first, right?

Comment: Sure. The use of an array there doesn't make any sense considering there will never be duplicate items. `struct Schedule {`
    `let title: String`
    `let classTypes: Set<String>`
`}`

Comment: @LeoDabus That's true and I assume order doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes you are probably right. if OP needs a specific order then he would need to keep the data inside an array. I think the order probably matters considering it is a schedule

Comment: Thanks both - I'll try it out.  Order does not matter - I'm just trying to find the set of schedules that have ALL types of classes that are in the filter array.

Comment: This did the trick.  Hadn't dealt with Sets before - game changing!